# calculate performance vs. buy and hold for a period

Tags: rate-of-return

If I know the daily performance of an investment strategy vs. buy and hold for a certain number of days, how can I get the performance over an entire period?

For example:

day 1) vs. Buy hold = 3%
  day 2) vs. Buy hold = 2%
  ...
  day 30) vs Buy hold = 7%

What is the formula to calculate the total performance vs Buy hold over x days?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compound the daily returns: (1 + 0.03) * (1 + 0.02) * ... * (1 + 0.07) - 1.